# Why is this while statement creating an infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, while-loop, continue

Without the if statement this loops works fine, however as soon as I add the if statement it turns it into an infinite loop-why? From my understanding continue should make the loop skip an iteration and then run as normal?

```
 let num=0;
 while(num<10){
        if(num===4){console.log("skipping "+num);
                continue;
    }
     console.log(num++);
}
```

Comment: because you forever skipping at no 4

Comment: @what do you want to print `0` or `1` as the first number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need also to increment the `num` in the `if` block. Without it after the if statement it never reaches to the `num++` and you never change the value of `num`, so it stays 4 and every time goes into the `if`. You can add `++` in the `if` statement.

```js
let num = 0;

while(num < 10) {
    
    if(++num === 4) { 
        console.log("skipping " + num);
        continue;
    }
    
    console.log(num);
}
```

Comment: Note that by using `++num` in the `if` condition you've changed the output to the console in both `.log()` statements.

Comment: You mean missing `0`?

Comment: It doesn't just miss `0`, the number output on each iteration is one higher than it otherwise would've been.

Comment: Try again. Now it logs `skipping 4`. In OP it also must log `skipping 4`

Comment: Yes, sorry, I misspoke about that (and edited my comment before I saw your reply). But it logs `skipping 4` on the *fourth* iteration, whereas the OP's code logged it on the *fifth* iteration.

Comment: Yes its about starting from `0`. In thic particular case he can just start from `-1` as I guess this is for learning purposes

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `while` loop when `num` gets incremented to `4`, it enters the `if` block and you are not incrementing `num` inside if block.

Also you are using `continue` which skips the code in the current iteration and moves to the next iteration. This keeps on happening and num is never incremented which leads to an infinite loop.

The following code prints numbers from **0 to 9** skipping 4 as asked in the question.

```
let num = 0;

while(num < 10) {

    if(num === 4) { 
        console.log("skipping " + num++);
        continue;
    }

    console.log(num++);
}
```

Comment: OP would be better off with a `for` loop, so that the counter can be incremented in a single place in the code regardless of whether there was a `continue`.